# mute individual Skype text chat?

Tags: windows, skype

My workplace uses Skype exclusively for individual and group chats. Messages are posted to the group chats several times a minute.

I would like to mute the constant audible notification for group chats, but keep them turned on for the more important private chats.

Is this possible with the 1st party Windows client?

Answer (score 34):

Yes this is possible.

If you use the '/alertson' command while in chat, it will only alert when it sees matching strings.  Example:

```
/alertson help yt joe meeting
```

will alert on any occurance of those four words.  I use this extensively for team/group chats that can be otherwise noisy.  I generally alert on my name as well as some common attention-getting strings.

In the latest skype client, the alert strings can also be seen by opening Conversation->Notification Settings and selecting:
(*) Notify me only if these words are mentioned

Comment: Once /alertson is called, is there any way to get it back to alert on everything again?

Comment: /alertson
with no arguments seems to do the trick

Comment: This is the most helpful thing I ever use for skype!

Answer (score 11):

For the simplest way just type `/alertsoff` in the chat window you want to mute (it doesn't matter if it's an individual or group chat).

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the actual group (or chat) -> Manage group -> Notifications (ON/OFF)